# What is the best way to shift my company name to the bottom

Tags: html, css

I have the following html as part of my layout page:-

```
<div class="top-nav nav-collapse">
<ul class="nav">                     
<li class="customTitle">custome Title </li>
<li>
</li></ul>
</div>
```

but the title was at the top of the page as follow:-
[image]

so I added a 
 before the title text as follow:-

```
<div class="top-nav nav-collapse">
<ul class="nav">                     
<li class="customTitle"><br/>custome Title </li>
<li>
</li></ul>
</div>
```

and the title was shifted to the bottom as follow:-

[image]
but my question is wheatear adding the `<br/>`, is the right approach to follow to achieve my layout requirement ?

thnaks

Comment: I usually will do it changing the line-height value

Comment: Or add some padding / margin. I wouldn't use the `<br/>`, that is for text, not for layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adjusting the `line-height` of the `.customTitle` class. In particular, if you set `line-height` to be equal to the `height`, then your text will appear in the middle of the title bar.

Comment: line-height worked well, but what do u mean by "set line-height to be equal to the height". i set the line-height to be 1em , while the text size is 3.77 em; and it worked well. any comment on my apprahc ?

Comment: Well, if you have a bar that has `height:100px;`, then you set `line-height:100px;` and the text will be vertically-aligned to the middle.

Answer (score 3):

try this one,

```
.customTitle
{
line-height:(somevalue)px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Use [padding-top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-top): which sets the top padding (space) of an element

```
.nav .customTitle { padding:YYYpx; }
```

or

[line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height): specifies the line height

```
 .nav .customTitle { line-height:XXXpx; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Never use`<br/>`'you can use padding or line height.

```
.customTitle
{
line-height:___px;
}
```

or

```
.customTitle
{
padding-top:___px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never use `<br/>` for styling!

You can use

```
li.customTitle { line-height:...; }
```

or

```
li.customTitle { padding:...px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can youse `style` tag. And give padding....

```
<li class="customTitle"><span style="padding-top:10px">custome Title</span> </li>
```

you can adjust height according to your need....